# Longblob do Mysql só aceita arquivo até 128mb

Tags: mysql, longblob

Crie uma tabela para armazenar arquivos, mas toda vida que envio um arquivo acima de 128mb todas as colunas ficam null, exceto o id. Percebi também que ele salva somente imagens, outro tipo de arquivo ele não quer salvar, como arquivo zip por exemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE Arquivo (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    nome varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    binario longblob,
    tipo varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: O arquivo realmente precisa ser salvo dentro do dB, será que você não poderia simplesmente salvar o arquivo em uma pasta e adicionar o caminho salvo no dB?

Comment: Não daria, pois o servidor usado possui um pequeno limite de disco rígido,e o servidor do Mysql tem um limite muito superior.

Comment: Offtopic: nossa que servidor horrível, eu tinha um servidor que o disco é "ilimitado" e pagava bem pouco 8 dólares por mês, hoje uso um VPS, mas o custo benefício ainda sim é ótimo. Espero que alguém consiga lhe responder

Comment: Eu pensei a mesma coisa, mas eu pago 1,50$, então não para reclamar muito, estou pensando seriamente em pagar mais por um VPS.